# Android transistions not working

Tags: android, overriding, transition

I have a start screen with a short delay, after the delay it moves onto the splashscreen however I cant seem to override the transition and I cant see why...Although the transition does work in debug mode which is very strange

```
package com.example.android.bubblestrouble;
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Team extends Activity{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final int delay = 3000;
    setContentView(R.layout.team);
    Thread welcomeThread = new Thread()
    {
    int wait = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        try {
                super.run();
                /**
                * use while to get the splash time. Use sleep() to increase
                * the wait variable for every 100L.
                */
                while (wait < delay) 
                {
                    sleep(100);
                    wait += 100;
                }
            } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            /**
            * Called after splash times up. Do some action after splash
            * times up. Here we moved to another main activity class
            */
            startActivity(new Intent(Team.this, SplashScreen.class));
            Team.this.finish();
            Team.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, R.anim.hold);
        }
    }
    };
    welcomeThread.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Straight solution. Show your splash image immediately on activity start and replace in with the needed layout by timer. Something like this(`onCreate` event of `Team` activity):

```
ImageView splashImage = new ImageView(this);
splashImage.setImageBitmap(splashBitmap); // or drawable/resource - as you like
setContentView(splashImage);
Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sleep(3000);
        Team.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentView(R.layout.team);
            }
        });
    }
}
timerThread.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for that although that isnt best practise for this application. The main issue is that I cant see why overridePendingTransition is not working. I am trying to use transition effects and this is the best way to implement this

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the sleep cycle? Try using `sleep(3000)` instead of incrementation